# Objective-C Bool Literals and Macros

Tags: objective-c

Disclaimer: limited knowledge of Objective-C (passing curiosity).

```
if (@YES)
```

vs

```
if (YES)
```

What's the difference?

From what I understand, @YES is a bool object literal, and YES is a macro that expands to 1? Is this correct? If so, why use @YES instead of YES or vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@YES` is a shortcut for `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`, so this:

```
if (@YES)
```

actually means

```
if ([NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] != nil)
```

Note, that it doesn't matter what number (or bool value) that is. You just test that it's a valid object. Even `@NO` will evaulate to `YES` if you test it like that, because it's a non-nil `NSNumber` instance:

```
if (@NO) NSLog(@"test");
```

Output:

```
2013-12-07 21:02:49.828 MyApp[37512:70b] test
```

Long story short: Don't use `@YES` or `@NO` like that, they will not behave as you would expect.

Comment: @Aristides: No, but `@YES`, `@NO`, `YES` and `1` are all *non-zero*, and that is what counts in the if-expression.

Comment: @Aristides `if (@NO)` is different from `if (NO)`.  The former is testing whether `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` returns a valid object (it does).  The latter is actually testing if the value is false.

Comment: That's what I meant. if (@literal) then simply tests if it returns an object (which in any case it would, right) while if (NO) becomes if (0) and therefore the actual intended test?

Answer (score 1):

`@YES, @1, @1.5`...these are all literal syntax that are the equivalent of an NSNumber ie: 
`[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`, `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`, `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.5]`.
Using this means you are creating an NSNumber object.

`YES` is simply the `BOOL` type, it's a primitive type in Obj-C, not an object like `NSNumber`. The `BOOL` type is used in Objective-C to hold true or false values. This is what you would normally use. You would only use `@YES` in cases where you need to hold the primitives in something that only accepts objects, perhaps if you wanted to hold them in an `NSArray` for example.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` symbol is a recent addition to Objective-C, which changes literals into their object representation in the form of an `NSNumber` instance.

This is especially useful if you need to store literals in arrays and dictionaries, which can only store objects (type `id`).

The way you use it, there is not need to create an object for the literal, so you should just use the literal directly.

The `@` symbol has always been used for denoting `NSString` objects, and only 2-3 years ago this syntax was extended for literals and expressions.

Comment: I know you meant something different, but *The @ symbol is a recent addition to Objective-C* is kind of funny. `@` is as old as Objective-C.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I know you meant something different, but *@ is as old as Objective-C* is kind of funny. `@` is more than 500 years old.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella :)